# De-duplicate smart random row query?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

following some research, I found a query suitable for my needs: it randomly returns IDs from the table. The ID field is an auto-increment, so there are no holes.

```
SELECT `mydb`.`myTable`.id
FROM   (SELECT Floor (Rand() * (SELECT Count(*) 
                                FROM   `mydb`.`myTable`)) num, 
               @num := @num + 1 
        FROM   (SELECT @num := 0) a, 
               `mydb`.`myTable` 
        LIMIT  2000000) b, 
       `mydb`.`myTable` 
WHERE  b.num = `mydb`.`myTable`.id
```

The issue I experience is that the target table (myTable) contains 30-400M records, depending on the situation. In the LIMIT, I want to retrieve 2M randomly selected IDs, however I get a lot of duplicates (which is expected).

Is it possible to de-duplicate the query and yet receive 2M records? I thought to create a table and let it manage the UNIQUE values, but again I will get less than expected.

Any thoughts? Many thanks!

Comment: Just a quick idea -> extend your table with dynamically created column with random values, and take 2M from TOP ordered by that column.

Comment: Put the `limit` outside the subquery

Comment: Just a note that auto-increment doesn't guarantee there are no "holes". Rows can be deleted leaving gaps in the id field.

Comment: @Barranka: thanks for the suggestion! Should it look like this?
` SELECT d.subscriber_id, @num as a FROM (
  SELECT `ip_warm_up`.`subscriber`.subscriber_id
  FROM   (SELECT Floor (Rand() * (SELECT Count(*) 
          FROM   `ip_warm_up`.`subscriber`)) num, 
        @num := @num + 1 
    FROM   (SELECT @num := 0) a, 
        `ip_warm_up`.`subscriber` 
    ) b, 
      `ip_warm_up`.`subscriber` 
  WHERE  b.num = `ip_warm_up`.`subscriber`.subscriber_id
 ) d
 GROUP BY d.subscriber_id
 HAVING count(*) = 1
 LIMIT  10;`
It takes **ages** to give results in a 30M-row table... Any thoughts?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: that's an excellent idea, thanks! just implemented it, however should I create an index for the 'rand' column? If I do, data infile takes ages to load the file. If I don't, I get no results when I add: `ORDER BY sb.rand ASC`. Any thoughts as well?

@SomeSillyName: thankfully, these tables are temporary, so there are no row deletions.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply order your rows by random. Than there are no duplicates and it doesn't matter if you have holes or not.

```
SELECT 
   id
FROM
  mydb.myTable
ORDER BY
  RAND()
LIMIT 2000000
```